# Google Apps Script: update cell to file name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to update a cell to the files name. I created a simple script with the following

```
function fileName() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
}
```

This works by setting a cell to `=fileName()`

However, if I change the file name this does not update. How can I get this update to happen when the file name changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it without a formula.
anytime the sheet is edited it will update the cell.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssName = ss.getName();
  ss.getRange('A1:A1').setValue(ssName);  //change A1:A1 to whatever cell you would like
}
```

Comment: This requires editing the file as well but I'll take it! I'll be using this when making copies of my invoices.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd add this as well. You can also add a trigger to any function since next to play & debug there is an option for triggers which you can customize to any function.

[Here is a link to the image of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toUwm.png)

```
var workBookName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
var someVariableName = sheet.getRange("G3").getValue();

var newWorkbookName = sheet.getRange("F3").getValue() + "_ConcatString_" + someVariableName // if you want to concat some values
Logger.log(workBookName);
Logger.log(newWorkbookName);
if (newName.toString().length>0 && workBookName !== newWorkbookName) {
  workBook.rename(newWorkbookName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [onOpen trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopen), so the cell will update each time your file is open:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(ss.getName());  
}
```